# What antd column render parameters stand for

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am new to antd and I've been wondering how does antd  column render function work, what do parameters of render stand for (text and record)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about `antd table column` ? 
In table column...
 `record` parameter stands for `each object of an arr` that is passed into the table as `data`. you can check & give `necessary condition` by using `record` parameter...
check out here.. you can read about all methods here.. 
https://ant.design/components/table/#API